# ConcurrentModificationError - but no modifications?

Tags: java, android, concurrentmodification

I have this piece of code:

```
public static final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

public static void sendMessage(final ArrayList<String> JIDs, final String text) {
    synchronized (MainActivity.getContext()) {
        if (JIDs != null) {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if (Looper.myLooper() == null) {Looper.prepare();}
                        for (String JID : JIDs) {
                            if (JID != null) {
                                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                                sendIntent.setAction("message.platform.SEND_MESSAGE");
                                sendIntent.putExtra("jid", JID);
                                sendIntent.putExtra("content", text);
                                MainActivity.getContext().sendBroadcast(sendIntent);
                            }
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(300);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
                Thread t = new Thread(r);
                t.start();
                try {t.join();} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What it's supposed to do is iterate over the list of different JID's and send them each the same message with a 300ms delay in between each message. This process has to be synchronized and locked, because I don't want multiple threads  accessing this code at the same time. It also runs on another thread while executing this code because of the needed 300ms delay (don't want to do that on the UI).

However, after multiple hours of running this code successfully, it always goes wrong with this error:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:573)
```

And then points at this piece of code in my method:

```
>>> for (String JID : JIDs) {
```

As far as I am concerned I am not modifying this list in any way shape or form... what is going on? And why does it work for hours and then randomly spit out this error? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I call the method like so:

```
sendMessage(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("jid1","jid2")),"Hello everyone!");
```

Comment: How do you call this method?

Comment: BTW: your `lock.unlock()` should be in a `finally` block.

Comment: Is that the *only* way you call the method?

Comment: Yes absolutely the only way as far as I am concerned, why is that?

Comment: Because it's not obvious how that list would ever be modified, like you say.

Comment: And thanks for the finally tip :) I put it in the last t.join try{}catch{}finally block

Comment: I know you say that it takes hours to fail, but can you try calling it with `sendMessage(Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("jid1","jid2"))),"Hello everyone!");` - that way, you will see where it is modified.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed it up! I will try to run the code for a few hours with unmodifiableList and see what goes wrong. :-) Thanks for the debugging tip

Comment: Same as @AndyTurner, but simpler is using: Arrays.asList("jid1","jid2"). This will give you an fixed-size list. You do not need the construcor, if your list is unmodifiable.

Comment: @TobiasOtto yes, that is relevant because it's only structural modification which causes the CME. However, making it *properly* unmodifiable (as in, you can't call `set` either) may find other cases of unexpected modification. If it takes hours to repro, you may as well go the whole shebang. OTOH, failing on `set` might happen before the structural modification; so maybe one is worth eliminating first.